# Airflow - dynamically create tasks based on external input

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I have a DAG that is triggered only externally (via API call). Each time the DAG is triggered it should process different input - it should have different part of the DAG (several tasks are common for all runs, and one taskgroup is dynamic). What I do now is that I save some data into JSON file onto PVC, then I have PythonOperator in Airflow that is running KubernetesPodOperator that is reading the JSON file and outputs its content to XCOM and then to airflow Variable. Then, based on this Variable I dynamically create tasks in this dynamic task group.

```py
def _read_request(**context):
    read_file = DefaultKubernetesPodOperator(
        image = 'ubuntu:22.04',
        cmds = ['bash', '-cx'],
        arguments = ['cat request.json >> /airflow/xcom/return.json'],
        name = 'some-name',
        task_id = 'some_name',
        do_xcom_push = True,
        image_pull_policy = 'IfNotPresent',
    )

    Variable.set(key = 'request', value = read_file.execute(context), serialize_json = True)


with dag:
    read_request = PythonOperator(task_id = 'read_file', python_callable = _read_request)
    request = Variable.get('request', default_var = default_request, deserialize_json = True)
    apples = request['apples']

    start = EmptyOperator(task_id = 'start', dag = dag)
    static_task = SomeCustomOperator(
        name = 'some-name',
    )
    with TaskGroup('dynamic', dag = dag) as dynamic_tasks:
        for apple in apples:
            task = CustomOperator(
                name = f'dynamic-task-{apple["name"]}',
                some_other_parameter='whatever'
            )
    (
        start
        >> read_request
        >> static_task
        >> dynamic_tasks
    )
```

Is this good approach? Is there any other way how to achieve this?

One issue that could happen is when I run 2 different requests simultaneously, Airflow creates 2 runs (which is correct), however, it takes some time to start the pod, read the json file and set the variable, therefore the first run takes wrong (newest) version of that JSON file.

Comment: I have one question: why you need a Kubernetes operator running a bash command to read a file? wouldn't not be enough a basoperator?. Things a side I think you can use xcom pull to recover your logs, to avoid having reading wrong json info

Comment: The file is stored on PVC that is in different namespace than the Airflow itself. I think I cannot run BashOperator over different PVC, can I?